# How can I adjust the margins of quote symbols added with CSS

Tags: html, css, margin, double-quotes

I'm trying to add quotation marks using only CSS. This works, but I'd like to lower the quotation marks with respect to the content inside them. This is how it currently looks:

[image: Screen grab of high quotation marks]

The HTML:

```
<p id="quote">This is a quotation.</p>
```

The CSS:

```
#quote {
}

#quote:before {
    content: "\201C";
    font-family: Garamond, Palatino, Roman, "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-size: 36pt;
}

#quote:after {
    content: "\201D";
    font-family: Garamond, Palatino, Roman, "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-size: 36pt;
}
```

And a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uZTj7/).

I've tried adding a top margin to `#quote:before` and `#quote:after` but this seems to apply to the text between the quotes too (even if I specifically add a zero or negative top margin to that). I've also tried padding and making the various elements inline blocks.

Is there a way to move just the quotes down using CSS? I'd rather avoid changing the HTML structure or adding images, and I feel this ought to be possible.

Comment: could you include the quotes in the html? Then you could give them their own style inside a `<span>` and adjust their css `line-height`? Quotes are part of the content so it should make sense for them to be in the html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding:

```
position: relative;
top: 19px;
```

to `#quote:before` and `#quote:after`.

I also added some padding to both quotes...

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/leniel/GAaBT/

Comment: Thanks. On my actual page that does indeed move the quotes down. However, when I scroll the page down, the quotes stay in a fixed position. Any idea what might be going on?

Comment: They should be in a fixed position, that is, they should move with your quoted text. This may be happening given the container you have in your page... Can you post the HTML where this quote is placed? The CSS you're applying to the container can influence the behavior... I added more text to the page and the quotes are fixed even when scrolling: http://jsfiddle.net/leniel/GAaBT/1/

Comment: Actually, changing it to use `position: absolute` without specifying the actual position seems to be working nicely. They're actually inside a container that itself has `:before` and `:after` styles, so perhaps that's affecting it.

Comment: Sure... so changing it to `absolute` does the job. Awesome. Just test it in all browsers you support and stick with it! :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you have applied the font-size property to the quotes instead of the text, that's why the quotes have become to big. Try this.

```
#quote {
    font-size:36px;
}

#quote:before {
    content: "\201C";
}

#quote:after {
    content: "\201D";
}
```

Comment: No, I want big quotes. I just want to nudge them down slightly with respect to the content inside them.